# Problem during SSL connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssl

I want to connect to my local SQL Server 2008 database using SSL.

I didn't install any certificates on the server because according to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx

> If a trusted certificate is not installed, SQL Server will generate
>   a self-signed certificate when the instance is started, and use the
>   self-signed certificate to encrypt the credentials.

This is simple code

```
SqlConnection connection = 
    new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=somePC\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=test;integrated security = sspi;Persist Security Info=True;Encrypt=true;");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Employee", connection);
connection.Open();
int employeeCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();`
```

Note that `encrypt=true;`

but on `connection.Open()` an exception is raised with message

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then
>   an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL
>   Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority
>   that is not trusted.)

Have can I approve this self-signed certificate ?

Answer (score 10):

You need to tell your client to trust whatever certificate is presented.  A self-signed certificate will not be trusted because it's not signed by any CA your computer trusts.  Change your connection by adding TrustServerCertificate=True as follows:

```
SqlConnection connection = 
    new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=somePC\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=test;integrated security = sspi;Persist Security Info=True;Encrypt=true; TrustServerCertificate=True");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Employee", connection);
connection.Open();
int employeeCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

> In order for RPC over Http to work you must have a Trusted CA Root
>   Certificate installed and configured. In a situation where you are
>   using a self-signed cert you will need to install the certificate into
>   the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

[Install the cert into your trusted root store.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx)

Comment: actually a haven't it.  SQL Server will generate a self-signed certificate when the instance is started