# An error occured during the pre-login handshake

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, sqlexception

I had a C# application that communicates with a database using Linq to SQL and was working just fine when I last tested it a month ago. However, it is now throwing the following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
------ Exception ------
Error:  A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The received certificate has expired.)
```

I am digitally signing the code with a Verisign key, but it has not expired. I don't digitally sign until I build the installer, and this is occurring on my dev system in debug, so the code had not been signed.

It is also happening on other systems where the software was signed and installed. These systems access the same test database as I use on my dev system, and were working previously.

The line of code that causes the error follows:

```
        List<req> results = new List<req>();

        using (var db = new MyDbDataContext(connectionString))
        {
            var query =
                from item in db.reqs
                where item.senddate == null
                select item;

            results = query.ToList();
        }
```

The error happens when I call `results = query.ToList();`.

I use the following connection string:

```
Data Source=<removed>;Initial Catalog=<removed>;UID=sa;PWD=<removed>;Encrypt=true;Integrated Security=false
```

I am able to connect if I set Encrypt=false, but that is not a viable solution.

Again, this worked just fine the last time I tested it a couple weeks ago. Any insights as to what might be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the database you're attempting to connect to on a different machine to the client? Are you using encrypted connections as described in "[Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx)"? *Has* the certificate expired, if so?

Comment: The Db is on a separate server within the company network. I am using Windows authentication and encryption. The Verisign certificate has not expired.

Comment: Double-check that you are hitting the right database server.

Comment: @Tim: Is the server set to `ForceEncryption=Yes`? If not, can you try a non-encrypted connection and see what happens? And by "the Verisign certificate", you do mean the certificate on the SQL Server, right, not the one you are using to digitally sign your code?

Comment: @Carson63000: I added my connection string to the question above. I made a mistake; I was not using Windows Authentication. I tried setting Encrypt=false, and was able to connect. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried using Windows Authentication in my connection, but this method failed with the same error.

Comment: Speaking with people who are using the software, I found that one person was connected to a database on her own computer. If a security certificate expired, wouldn't that be restricted to a single install of SQL. However, I'm not sure what certificate I might be passing that could expire.

Comment: @Tim, I do think expiration could be restricted to a single install, unless several installs have (about) the same expiration date. But you should not look at your code signing, but at a SQL certificate. Here is a lengthy post about that: http://thesqldude.com/2012/04/21/setting-up-ssl-encryption-for-sql-server-using-certificates-issues-tips-tricks/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find a solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024277/problem-during-ssl-connection-to-sql-server).

Basically, I added `TrustServerCertificate=True` to my connection text, and everything started working again. I'm not sure why it stopped working in the first place, and if anyone knows if this will be a permanent solution or not, I would love to find out more about what happened.

Thank you to Carson63000 and Jacco for the suggestions.