# Remote SQL Servers unavailable after installing Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I just built a new machine after my old one crashed a few days ago.  I'm running Windows 7.  I installed SQL Server 2012 Express as well as SQL Server Development Edition with Tools.

After installing, I made sure I could connect to both the Express version, local Dev server as well as multiple remote servers.  Everything was great.

This morning, I installed Visual Studio 2012.  Since doing this, I can still connect to my Local servers (Express and Dev), but I can't connect to the remote servers.  The error I get is this:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

I've searched for issues, and while I've found some similar to this, not many mention Visual Studio, and none offer a solution.

**UPDATE**

I found I can connect using Named Pipes.  The problem then is that not all my servers are configured to allow Named Pipes.

Comment: Facing same issue. Even the utility 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81e1b380-afe1-46ad-9c91-a588e0a5aa4b/how-to-reenable-remote-sql-server-connections-after-installing-visual-studio-2012 didn't find any mistake

Comment: Kamran Shahid see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users are experiencing this problem, I thought I would add the solution I found.

The utility lspfix.exe found a break in the Layered Service Provider (LSP) chain. I applied the recommended fix and I was up and running again.

The fix was recommended by the lspfix.exe application.  It's a very simple tool to use and it found the problem quickly.  Here is the url to the tool.

http://www.cexx.org/lspfix.htm

Comment: Hi Jeff.I have also tried it but there is no problem found message when i ran the utility.
Then i follow the solution mentioned in my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716897/not-able-to-connect-any-remote-database-server-after-installing-visual-studio-20/18719650#18719650 which did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studion Connection Related Error:

**netsh winsock reset**
Run this command in command prompt. That will Fix Connection Related Error in Visual studio 2012

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to look in your SQL server configuration manager and make sure TCP/IP is enabled for the database instances your interested in.

It isn't by default if I remember rightly.

If you're ok locally, have you read this post?

[An error occured during the pre-login handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206980/an-error-occured-during-the-pre-login-handshake)

Comment: Ah wait, sorry, mis-read the question, you're ok on local boxes you say?

Comment: Local connections work fine. Nothing has changed on the servers.  No one else is running into this problem.  I had this problem before when installing .NET 4.5 on my old machine. As per most of the solutions found, uninstalling .NET 4.5 and/or Visual Studio 2012 was the answer.  I don't want to go that route.