# Not able to connect any remote database server after installing Visual studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a machine which has VS2010 and sql server 2005, 2008 installed.
I were able to connect every remote database server from my application prior to installing VS2012. After installing VS2012 I am getting "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." on code where i have database call.
If i try to connect local database it connects fine.
Also what i tried is connect via server explorer in Visual studio 2010. It connects to local source successfully.
But when i try to connect to remote source it crashes VS2010 and Get following error in Event viewer

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f2a73
Faulting module name: netconfig.dll, version: 1.0.0.5, time stamp: 0x50a60f11
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000fdac
Faulting process id: 0xb40
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceae0dd4041a18
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\imonagent\netconfig.dll
Report Id: 5fec2d1f-1a01-11e3-bf8e-4c001050978f
```

I have read following post and downloaded utility but it also not indicates any error in my machine
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81e1b380-afe1-46ad-9c91-a588e0a5aa4b/how-to-reenable-remote-sql-server-connections-after-installing-visual-studio-2012

Please help me what to do with this problem
Problem not only occurs while i am debugging but also if somebody trying to view hosted site in my machine which has some remote database server connection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a luck via running following command (netsh Winsock reset) from command prompt mentioned in 
social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2d11b6f9-3ada-4682-b643-c721a97af4ba/cant-connect-to-database-after-installing-vs-11-pro-beta

Comment: This command saved a lot of time, I spent hours but couldn't get it fixed. Thanks